# xdf files adding calculated columns

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I am using Microsoft-R, and have an XDF file that has 50 columns. I would like to perform some calculations on these columns, that will constitute let's say 10 new columns. I would like to then add these new columns to the existing XDF file. Would you know how to do this?

Thanks.
Thomas.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/LearnAnalytics-mr4ds

Comment: hi @HongOoi Thanks for that link, but could you please be a bit more specific? Thanks.